# True HMVC/PAC in kohana PHP framework

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana, kohana-3

I'm new to PHP and use of PHP frameworks. I chose Kohana PHP as my framework for a project I am working on (instead of alloy, also because it's the least complicated). Is there a way to implement MVC triad hierarchy in my Kohana project?

> folder (root folder for mvc)
>   -|-subfolder
>   ----models
>   ----views
>   ----controllers
>  
>   -|-subfolder 2
>   ----models
>   ----views
>   ----controllers

If anyone could help me in routing and forms for this kind of implementation, I would gladly appreciate it :)

note: I did browse through kohana's 3.3 docu, and I just don't get how to actually implement this

Comment: Get in touch with the documentation, I found good examples when I started working with Kohana. Also there are plenty of tutorials (e.g. kerkness.ca). You can easily use subfolders within models, views and controllers

Comment: I have the full docu. but are modules different from what I want to acheive?

Comment: kingero can you give me some examples?

Comment: What do your subfolders represent? You can share the kohana system and should be able to use own m/v/c in one subfolder at a time

Comment: i wanted to implement mvc triads in kohana. it helps create a more enclosed space to play with. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one 'system' and 'modules' directory and different 'application' folder in one project. But there are some problems with routing(its really ugly) and code duplication (logs, configs etc.)